# How to avoid derived column date conversion error with a value containing zeroes?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a comma delimited text file that I import into SQL server 2008 using an SSIS package.  As part of the package I have a derived column as part of the text file is an end date.  THe problem I have is if there is no end date the text file has **`00000000`** instead of a real date such as **`20130207`**.  In my derived column editor I have the following expression which works fine for dates that arent all zero's.

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Column 20],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 20],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 20],7,2))
```

Can anyone offer a solution or assistance on how best to handle the zeros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cause:

The Derived Column transformation is trying to convert the value `00000000` to the date `00-00-0000`, which is not considered as a valid date value.

#### Option 1: Database column allows NULL

If your database column is defined as **`NULL`**, which means that it can accept *NULL* values, change the expression in the *`Derived Column`* transformation as following:

```
[Column 20] == "00000000" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Column 20],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 20],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 20],7,2))
```

#### Option 2: Database column does not allow NULL

If your database column is defined as **`NOT NULL`**, which means that it cannot accept *NULL* values, change the expression in the *`Derived Column`* transformation as following:

```
[Column 20] == "00000000" ? (DT_DATE) "1900-01-01" : (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Column 20],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 20],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 20],7,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[Column 20] = "00000000" ? (DT_DATE("19000101") : (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Column 20],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 20],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 20],7,2))
```

Essentially, what its trying to do is checking if the Column 20 is eight zeros then it associates a date 01-01-1900 otherwise it converts what it finds in Column 20